# How is internet based proof of age verifiable in a yes or no popup or an agree to terms and conditions disclaimer admissable?

Tags: minor, consent, age

If I am visiting a bar or especially a club I am ID'd especially here in the UK. But for a porn site anyone can enter and exit by just self verifying yes or no. That's an extreme example. But when you read terms and conditions of popular apps such as Facebook, WhatsApp and many other sites why is it that the person clicking yes or no is not legally challenged about their credentials especially when the party asking has set those terms?

Comment: It’s the difference between “you made no effort whatsoever to keep underage people out” and “you made insufficient efforts to keep underage people out”. They tried, just not very well. It may be enough to avoid _some_ legal consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Admissibility is an evidence question. If there is a business record or sworn testimony that can establish a fact, and it is relevant, then it is admissible evidence at trial.

You really seem to be asking, instead, if this kind of measure, if it is established that it was taken with admissible evidence, should be sufficient as a matter of substantive law, to establish someone's age. Ultimately, Law.SE answers what the law is, of course, and not what it "should be".

There are federal laws and regulations that govern regulating the age of people using websites. Those laws are quite lenient, and really only currently require minimal, easily circumvented measures (although these measures are sufficient to prevent people with computers outfitted with age restricted software parental controls out), in part, because they only prevent people from seeing images or data over the web, and it is inherently difficult to regulate this (an older friend, or a fake login as a parent, for example, could circumvent it).

One of the main regulations if the [Children's Online Privacy Protection Rule](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule):

> COPPA imposes certain requirements on operators of websites or online
> services directed to children under 13 years of age, and on operators
> of other websites or online services that have actual knowledge that
> they are collecting personal information online from a child under 13
> years of age.

Lots of frequently asked questions about the rule are answered [here](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions-0). One of those rules notes that:

> Although COPPA does not apply to teenagers, the FTC is concerned about
> teen privacy and does believe that strong, more flexible, protections
> may be appropriate for this age group. See FTC Report: Protecting
> Consumer Privacy in an Era of Rapid Change: Recommendations for
> Businesses and Policymakers (Mar. 2012), at 29, 60. The FTC also has
> issued a number of guidance documents for teens and their parents.
> These educational materials are available at [www.OnguardOnline.gov](http://www.OnguardOnline.gov).

Basically, for older teens, however, primary responsibility is placed on parents and guardians, and not on Internet Service providers.

More substantial limitations are generally imposed when web activity has some real world consequence like delivery of alcohol to a home, or purchasing something with a credit card.

The law could impose more strict standards, but so far, it doesn't.